# How can I concatenate two attributes per element in a single XPath function?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have the following XML:

```
<xml>
    <entry key="e1" value="foo"/>
    <entry key="e2" value="bar"/>
    ...
</xml>
```

I want to get the following output from an XPath:

```
e1: foo, e2: bar, ...
```

I tried to use `string-join` but it didn't work. Any ideas which version of XPath could do this? Is it even possible?

(Note: I'd rather prefer an XPath 1.0 query, however, I don't think it is possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried to use string-join but it didn't work. Any ideas on which XPath could do this? Is it even possible?
>   [...] I don't think it is possible)

Why wouldn't it be possible?...

Anyway, as was also hinted at in the comments, just use

```
concat(
    entry[1]@key, ': ', 
    entry[1]@value, ', ', 
    entry[2]@key, ': ', 
    entry[2]@value)
```

Other ways:

- XPath 2.0: `string-join( (expr1, expr2, ...), '')`
- XSLT 2.0: `<xsl:value-of select="expr1, expr2, ..." separator="" />`
- XPath 3.0: `expr1 || expr2 || ...` using the string concatenation operator
- Any XSLT version, to prevent the repetition, use template matching:

  ```
  <xsl:template match="xml/entry">
      <xsl:value-of select="@key" />
      <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  ```
- Or more generic, apply templates on the attribute nodes and match as follows:

  ```
  <xsl:template match="@key | @value">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
      <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@value">
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  ```
- XSLT 3.0, write your templates with text-value-templates (TVT's):

  ```
  <xsl:template match="xml/entry" expand-text="yes">{
      @key}: {
      @value,
      if(position() != last()) then ',' else ()
  }</xsl:template>
  ```
- XPath 2.0, more generic approach:

  ```
  string-join(
      for $i in xml/item 
      return concat($i/@key, ': ', $i/@value),
      ', ')
  ```

  or shorter:

  ```
  string-join(xml/item/concat($i/@key, ': ', $i/@value, ', ')
  ```
- ... or using [higher-order functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83a4h3y3X9c) ([pdf](http://archive.xmlprague.cz/2013/presentations/Efficient_XML_processing_with_XSLT_3.0_higher_order_functions.pdf)) for fun and easier (?) reading in XPath 3.0:

  ```
  let $combine = concat(?, ': ', ?)
  return string-join(
      for $i in xml/item 
      return $combine($i/@key, $i/@value),
      ', ')
  ```

  or even:

  ```
  string-join(
      for-each-pair(
          xml/item/@key,       (: combine this :)
          xml/item/@value,     (: with this :)
          concat(?, ': ', ?)), (: using this, in order :)
      ', ')                    (: then join :)
  ```

Note: if you do not use XSLT, simply ignore the template approach, you can stick to the functions mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't want to use the elegant `string-join()` expression**:

```
string-join(/*/*/concat(@key, ': ', @value), 
            ', ')
```

**You may still use this somewhat longer expression**:

```
 /*/*/concat(@key, ': ', 
             @value, 
             if(following-sibling::*[1])
                then ', '
                else ()
             )
```

**Alternatively, you can use this XSLT 2.0 one-liner** (of course it needs to be included in an appropriate template, such as one matching `'/'`):

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*/*/concat(@key, ': ', @value)" separator="', '"/>
```